# copied site HTML code from Google Chrome's inspect element doesnt work full functional

Tags: html, google-chrome, web-crawler, inspect-element, velo

I am using wix.com to make sites,I was making a site for a company and i tried to embbed a the facebook page html of that company into one of the site pages but it doesnt fully load!it stops after viewing the n.o of likes.

I tried to embbed the website directly but the Facebook page doesnt load at all! so I thought of copying the code and adding it in the wix site

Here is a screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents are dynamically loaded by using ajax requests to facebook's server.
You copied the code and added it to your site. But since your domain name is different, facebook will prevent `Cross Origin Requests` and so you will get a `405` Error and the content will not be provided to you. That is the problem there.